# How do I query which database has a table named aaa?

Tags: mysql

There're too many databases,

how can I query which database has a table named `aaa` to narrow the range to search for?

Comment: select * from databasename.aaa is that you lookking for

Comment: @Roshan I think he's saying he has multiple databases and he doesn't know which one has a table named "aaa". He wants to know a way to find which database contains that table. At least, that's what I THINK he's asking for...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look at the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database for "meta" information such as which databases contain which schemata. For example, to find a list of databases that contain tables with the name `aaa`, run this query:

`SELECT schema_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name = "aaa"`

For more information on the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, see [the MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html).